# Detecting why files are being deleted from the server

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, lamp, delete-file

I'm working on a document management application on LAMP/php that lets you add and delete PDFs to our server. It works great, except for one nagging issue - the files you upload Monday might be gone Tuesday, and I can't diagnose why. it seems like the entire directory is getting deleted - my suspicion is that somewhere an incomplete string is getting passed to an unlink or something, but I've disabled every line of code I can find that removes files from the server and I'm still having trouble. How do I go about diagnosing the cause of these random disappearing files? Are there any utilities I can use to log any attempted removal of or changes to a file or directory?

Comment: Change the permissions on the folders and see where errors start appearing.

Comment: here is a link that could help you: http://linuxos4all.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-track-which-files-have-been.html

Comment: @pzirkind: That won't work if the files are removed by a PHP script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/304121/files-disappearing-on-linux-server

Comment: @InternetSeriousBusiness Interesting...Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Make an unlink wrapper function that tracks some extra data and update all the unlink functions in your app to use it. Something like unlink_custom(file,date-time,note) and then have that function log all requests so you can check back and see which ones are nuking your files.

Comment: It could be something outside your app, such as a cron running that prunes certain directories, though this is only likely if you're not alone on the server.

Comment: Note that, if you're using `unlink()` to delete files, that will only delete files or empty folders -- it'll refuse to delete folders which aren't empty. You may want to check if a search engine is crawling delete links somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

idealy you'd want to find your bug...

```
find codebase/ -type f -exec grep -il "unlink" '{}' \;
```

alertativley if you want a hacky fix, update your apache user to have a umask that would enable it to create files, but not delete them...

```
sed -i 's/^\(start|[a-z|-]*)\)/\1\n    umask 0222/' `which apachectl`
```

also this would generate permission dennied errors in the error log...

Comment: ``find codebase/ -type f | xargs grep -sl "unlink "`` is easier to remember ... just my 3.14 cents.

Comment: @Michael would you mind explaining what the find command does and how it will help solve the problem asked.